# Django: Static file path

Tags: django

I have a project, `myproject`, and an app, `myapp`. In a view function, I want to read a text file. The text file is located at `myproject/myapp/static/myapp/myfile.txt`. Static file configuration has been defined here:

**myproject/myproject/settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And the view function is here:

**myproject/myapp/views.py**

```
fp = open(static('myapp/myfile.txt'))
```

However, I get the error:
    **IOError at /myapp/
    No such file or directory: '/static/myapp/mydata.txt'**

Why is this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your static() method like, where do you get it from?

Comment: Also in my views.py file, I have "from django.templatetags.static import static"

Answer (score -1):

Static is a template tag. Thus, it is expected to be used within a template and will return results as part of the template rendering. So I am not sure if it works anyway.

However, if it works, it will not return the filepath on your filesystem, but it will return the URL path, where the static file can be downloaded.

So why are you using it anyway, you know where the file is in your app.